# Pandas pivot table Nested Sorting

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, nested-sortable

Given this data frame and pivot table:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['x','y','z','x','y','z'],
                 'B':['one','one','one','two','two','two'],
                 'C':[7,5,3,4,1,6]})
df


    A   B       C
0   x   one     7
1   y   one     5
2   z   one     3
3   x   two     4
4   y   two     1
5   z   two     6

table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['A', 'B'],aggfunc=np.sum)

table
A  B  
x  one    7
   two    4
y  one    5
   two    1
z  one    3
   two    6
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

I want to sort the pivot table such that the order of 'A' is z, x, y and the order of 'B' is based on the descendingly-sorted values from data frame column 'C'.

Like this:

```
A  B  
z  two    6
   one    3
x  one    7
   two    4
y  one    5
   two    1

    Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `z, x, y` is not sorted in any order.

Comment: Hi Alexander. Yes, that's because I want to be able to custom sort the order of the first index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is an easy way to accomplish your objective.  The following solution first sorts your table is descending order based on the values of column `C`.  It then concatenates each slice based on your desired order.

```
order = ['z', 'x', 'y']
table = table.reset_index().sort_values('C', ascending=False)
>>> pd.concat([table.loc[table.A == val, :].set_index(['A', 'B']) for val in order])
       C
A B     
z two  6
  one  3
x one  7
  two  4
y one  5
  two  1
```

Comment: Very nice. :) I try map by dictionary, but this is better.

Answer (score 2):

If you can read in column A as categorical data, then it becomes much more straightforward.  Setting your categories as `list('zxy')` and specifying `ordered=True` uses your custom ordering.

You can read in your data using something similar to:

```
'A':pd.Categorical(['x','y','z','x','y','z'], list('zxy'), ordered=True)
```

Alternatively, you can read in the data as you currently are, then use `astype` to convert A to categorical:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype('category', categories=list('zxy'), ordered=True)
```

Once A is categorical, you can pivot the same as before, and then sort with:

```
table = table.sort_values(ascending=False).sortlevel(0, sort_remaining=False)
```

Comment: I can't seem to implement what you mentioned.

Comment: I've edited my answer with an alternate way to convert to categorical data.  I'm assuming that's the part you can't implement?

Comment: Thanks, @root! That clarified it for me. Out of curiosity, I see another way to do it would be df['A'] = df['A'].astype('category') then in the next line, df['A'].cat.set_categories(['z','x','y'],inplace=True)    Is one method better than the other in certain situations?

Comment: I don't know enough about how pandas implements categorical data to say if one method is better than the other.  I prefer to do it all on a single line for conciseness, but that's purely personal style.

Comment: I found this answer useful and upvoted. However, using Pandas 1.0.1 `astype` seems to not accept categories argument. I'm getting: `TypeError: astype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categories'`. I was able to do this using CategoricalDtype (`from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype`). Then `cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=my_ordered_list,ordered=True)` and `df.astype(cat_type)`, according to [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html).

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

```
custom_order = ['z', 'x', 'y']
kwargs = dict(axis=0, level=0, drop_level=False)

new_table = pd.concat(
    [table.xs(idx_v, **kwargs).sort_values(ascending=False) for idx_v in custom_order]
)
```

## Alternate one liner

```
pd.concat([table.xs(i, drop_level=0).sort_values(ascending=0) for i in list('zxy')]
```

## Explanation

`custom_order` is your desired order.
`kwargs` is a convenient way to improve readability (in my opinion).  Key elements to note, `axis=0` and `level=0` might be important for you if you want to leverage this further.  However, those are also the default values and can be left out.
`drop_level=False` is the key argument here and is necessary to keep the `idx_v` we are taking a `xs` of such that the `pd.concat` puts it all together in the way we'd like.

I use a list comprehension in almost the exact same manner as Alexander within the `pd.concat` call.

## Demonstration

```
print new_table

A  B  
z  two    6
   one    3
x  one    7
   two    4
y  one    5
   two    1
Name: C, dtype: int64
```