# Pandas Multiindex Nested Sort and Percent

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, pivot-table, percentage

Given this data frame and pivot table:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'County':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
                'Hospital':['a','b','c','d','e','a','b','c','e','a','b','c','d','e','a','b','c','e'],
                'Enrollment':[44,55,42,57,95,54,27,55,81,54,65,23,89,76,34,12,1,67],
                'Year':['2012','2012','2012','2012','2012','2012','2012','2012','2012','2013',
                        '2013','2013','2013','2013','2013','2013','2013','2013']})
d2=pd.pivot_table(df,index='Year',columns=['County','Hospital'])
d2
            Enrollment
County      A                   B
Hospital    a   b   c   d   e   a   b   c   e
Year                                    
2012       44   55  42  57  95  54  27  55  81
2013       54   65  23  89  76  34  12  1   67
```

I'd like to do the following:

1. Calculate the percent of hospital 'Enrollment' (per county) for the most recent year like this:

   ```
               Enrollment                              
   County      A                   B           
   Hospital    a   b   c   d   e   a   b   c   e
   Year                                    
   2012        44  55  42  57  95  54  27  55  81
   2013        54  65  23  89  76  34  12  1   67
   Percent     18% 21% 7%  29% 25% 30% 11% 1%  59%
   ```
2. Sort the columns by 'Enrollment' (descendingly) for the most recent year like this:

   ```
               Enrollment                              
   County      A                   B           
   Hospital    d   e   b   a   c   e   a   b   c 
   Year                                    
   2012        57  95  55  44  42  81  54  27  55
   2013        89  76  65  54  23  67  34  12  1
   Percent     29% 25% 21% 18% 7%  59% 30% 11% 1%
   ```
3. Take the top 3 hospitals (in terms of enrollment for most recent year) per county like this:

   ```
               Enrollment                  
   County      A           B       
   Hospital    d   e   b   e   a   b 
   Year                        
   2012        57  95  55  81  54  27
   2013        89  76  65  67  34  12
   Percent     29% 25% 21% 59% 30% 11%
   ```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. So far, I've tried to sort by transposing and using county and the right-most column for the most recent year:

```
cnty=d2.T.index.names[1]
ryr=d2.T.columns[-1]
d2.T.sort_values([cnty,ryr],ascending=False)
```

...but I know I need to access 'County' differently as it's not a real column.

**Update:**

I can calculate the most recent year percent (and filter out) by transposing and using group by, though I'm sure there's a more efficient way.

```
d=d2.T
d['Percent']=(d.iloc[:,-1]/d.iloc[:,-1].sum()*100)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.groupby(level='County').apply(lambda x: x['2013'].div(x['2013'].sum())).reset_index(0, drop=True).to_frame('Percent')], axis=1)
top_3 = df.groupby(level='County')['Percent'].nlargest(3).reset_index(0, drop=True)
df = pd.concat([df.drop('Percent', axis=1), top_3], axis=1, join='inner')
df.groupby(level=1).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Percent', ascending=False)).reset_index(0, drop=True).T
```

to get:

```
                 A                                B                      
                 d          e          b          e          a          b
Year                                                                     
2012     57.000000  95.000000  55.000000  81.000000  54.000000  27.000000
2013     89.000000  76.000000  65.000000  67.000000  34.000000  12.000000
Percent   0.289902   0.247557   0.211726   0.587719   0.298246   0.105263
```

Comment: Thanks. Also this: d.sort_values(d2.T.columns[-1],ascending=False).sortlevel(1, sort_remaining=False)
as indicated by Jezrael here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147822/pandas-pivot-table-nested-sorting/37148717?noredirect=1#comment61837435_37148717

Answer (score 0):

So, I found that this works as well:

```
d=d2.T
d['Percent']=round(d.iloc[:,-1]/d.iloc[:,-1].groupby(level=1).transform(sum),2)
d=d.sort_values(d.columns[-1],ascending=False).sortlevel(1, sort_remaining=False)
d=d.groupby(level=1).head(3)
d.T
```