# Python Pivot tables custom sort x-axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table plot where the x-axis is custom sorted.
My code:

```
import pandas as pd
data_dict = {
    'x' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
    'y' : [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
}
res_table = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(res_table, 
                    index='x', values='y', 
                    aggfunc='sum')

ax = df_pivot.plot(kind='line', marker='*', title='y data')

ax.set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), loc="upper left")
ax.figure
```

This code gives this plot:

[image: graph]

Now I want to change the X-axis so that it start with 8 to 15 and then follows with 1 to 7. So that the graph becomes a straight line.

I tried this code: ([Pandas pivot table Nested Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147822/pandas-pivot-table-nested-sorting))

```
order = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
pd.concat([res_table.loc[res_table['x'] == val, :].set_index(['x']) for val in order])
```

But that doesn't seem to change anything.

*Edit: Of course I can add an extra column with the correct index and plot the graph using that but I would prefer the graph to show the real x value.

**Edit: I celebrated a bit to early.
My real code has extra columns to plot multiple of these lines on one graph

```
data_dict = {
    'x' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
    'y' : [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28],
    'z' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
}
res_table = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(res_table, 
                    index='x', values='y', 
                    aggfunc='sum', columns='z')

cut_val = 8
tmp_df = pd.concat((df_pivot.loc[cut_val:], 
                     df_pivot.loc[:cut_val-1])).reset_index()
print(tmp_df)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(tmp_df.index, tmp_df.y, '-o')
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticklabels(tmp_df.loc[ticks, 'x'])
ax.figure
```

The code stops at this line with a key error on tmp_df.y:

```
ax.plot(tmp_df.index, tmp_df.y, '-o')
```

Without the columns argument the code works fine

In the original code the graph looks like this
[image]

Comment: Do you know exactly where to cut, i.e. 8, or you need to detect it automatically?

Comment: Yes it is known where to cut the graph. In this case 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in this special case, we can do with a `sort_value` and `set_xticklabels`

```
df_pivot = df_pivot.sort_values('y').reset_index()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df_pivot.index, df_pivot.y, '-o')
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticklabels(df_pivot.loc[ticks, 'x'])
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

In general, you can make do with `concat` and then `set_xticklabels` in similar fashion

```
cut_val = 8
tmp_df = pd.concat((df_pivot.loc[cut_val:], 
                     df_pivot.loc[:cut_val-1])).reset_index()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(tmp_df.index, tmp_df.y, '-o')
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticklabels(tmp_df.loc[ticks, 'x'])
plt.show()
```

For you updated dataframe, `tmp_df` actually has several columns other, non is `y`, due to the unique values in `z`:

```
cut_val = 8
tmp_df = pd.concat((df_pivot.loc[cut_val:], 
                     df_pivot.loc[:cut_val-1])).reset_index()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

tmp_df[df_pivot.columns].plot(ax=ax, marker='o')
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticklabels(tmp_df.loc[ticks, 'x'])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Indeed in this case this is possible but my y-values are measured values and aren't guaranteed to always be nicely incrementing.

Comment: This indeed seems to do what I need. What is the variable plt? Because it is not defined anywhere?
Thanks already for the help

Comment: Common practice: `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`. Your `ax` is actually a `plt.Axes` object.

Comment: Thanks. That indeed seems to work. Only he shows the x-axis as starting from 0 instead of 8.. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I forgot `ax.set_xticklabels(tmp_df.loc[ticks, 'x'])` by the end. See update.

Comment: Thanks! Now I am having problems integrating this code into my real code.
In my real code I have some extra columns and use the 'columns' argument in my pivot_table call.
When i call ax.plot(tmp_df.index, tmp_df.<real name>, '-o') he doesnt seem to know the real name anymore. Without the 'columns' argument the code works but all values are added together.

Comment: in general, you should avoid doing `df.col_name` as it may clash with default pandas method/properties, i.e. `df.values`. Instead, do `df['col_name']`.

Comment: Yh i thought of that but that seems to work both ways give a keyerror when the columns argument is in the pivot_table. I will edit my question a bit that makes it more clear

Comment: I updated my example to make more clear what i mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196005/discussion-between-bramv-and-quang-hoang).